# Prove there is a full measure set s.t Birkhoff averages of any continuous function converge on that set

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space equipped with a Borel probability measure $\mu$. If $T$ is a continuous ergodic transformation, prove there is a full measure set s.t Birkhoff averages of any continuous function converge on that set.

I am only looking for hints.

My work: First of all, $C(X)$ is separable, so there is a dense sequence $f_k$. It is clear that there is a set of full measure s.t for each $k$ the Birkhoff averages converge to $\int f_k$. At this point I tried to do some limit argument to no avail. I get a double limit and I just cannot seem to justify why you can exchange the two limits. Thus I think I am looking at this problem the wrong way. Especially since I do not see why continuity of $T$ is needed here.

I would much appreciate advice/hints rather than flat out solutions.

Comment: @Adam It is ergodic

Comment: @Adam It is written in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first intuition is right. As $C(X)$ is separable you can find a dense sequence $f_k$. For every $f_k$ there is a full measure set $X_k$ for which the Birkhoff sums converge to the integrable.

Then a countable intersection of full measure set is a full measure set. So on the set $Y = \cap X_k$ every $f_k$ has its Birkhoff sums converging to its average.

No take a $g \in C(X)$. There is a subsequence $\{g_k\} \subset \{f_k\}$ such that for every $\epsilon$, there is a $K$ such that for every $k>K$, $|f-g_k|_\infty \leq \epsilon$.

So for every $x \in Y$, $|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(T^i(x))-\int g|=|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(T^i(x))-g_k(T^i(x))+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g_k(T^i(x))-\int g_k+\int (g_k-g)|$

But we have that $$
|\int (g_k-g)| \leq \epsilon Vol(X)
$$

$$
|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(T^i(x))-g_k(T^i(x))|\leq \epsilon
$$
And $$
\lim \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g_k(T^i(x))-\int g_k = 0
$$

So applying the triangular inequality to detach this three pieces we get that $$
\limsup |\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(T^i(x))-\int g| \leq \epsilon (1+ Vol(X))
$$
as this is true for every $\epsilon$ we have that $$
\limsup |\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(T^i(x))-\int g| =0
$$
And then $$
\lim |\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(T^i(x))-\int g| =0
$$

Comment: This argument can be generalized for any $f \in L^1$ correct? Since continuous functions are dense in $L^1$

Comment: In the space $L^1$ you can not really take the image of a point by the function. It is formally a equivalence class of function which differ by a zero-measure set. The corollary is that you can not say the Birkhoff sum at one point is converging. But you can say the function Birkhoff sum is converging to a constant function in $L^1$-norm.

Comment: See the first paragraph of https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch7.pdf